# Beginner scheme: How to make a binary arithmatic expression a string.

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to change a binary arithmetic expression into a string and I'm having trouble with the recursive part of it. So far I can only do the basic two.

```
(define-struct bae (fn arg1 arg2))
;; A binary arithmetic expression (binexp) is either
;; a number, or 
;; a structure (make-bae f a1 a2), where
;;   f is a symbol in the set'*,'+,'-,and'/,
;;   a1 is a binexp, and 
;;   a2 is a binexp.

(define (binexp->string b)
  (cond 
    [(number? b) (number->string b)]
    [else (string-append "(" (number->string (bae-arg1 b)) (symbol->string(bae-fn b))
              (number->string (bae-arg2 b))
              ")")]))

(check-expect (binexp->string 5) "5")
(check-expect (binexp->string (make-bae '* 3 4)) "(3*4)")
(check-expect (binexp->string ((make-bae '+
(make-bae '* (make-bae '+ 4 1)
(make-bae '+ 5 2))
(make-bae '- 6 3))) "(((4+1)*(5+2))+(6-3))")
```

This last check-expect is what I don't know how to do. Any help would be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.  You've got to recurse with `binexp->string` on `arg1` and `arg2` as:

```
(define (binexp->string b)
  (if (number? b)
      (number->string b)
      (string-append "("
                     (binexp->string (bae-arg1 b))
                     (symbol->string (bae-fn   b))
                     (binexp->string (bae-arg2 b))
                     ")")))
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I don't know how I didn't see this earlier!

Comment: Note: this is the sort of thing you should get directly by writing the function templates for your data structures first.